# How to Modified or permanently delete Field in the DBGrid with Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7, tclientdataset, dbgrid

how so that I can remove / modify fields in the DB Grid permanently?
I use this code:
NB : CDS = ClientDataSet
     DBG = DBGrid
     Database I use is *.xml

```
uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Forms, ExtCtrls, Buttons, DB, DBClient, DBGrids,
  Grids, Controls, StdCtrls, Dialogs, Classes;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
        B2: TSpeedButton;
        B3: TSpeedButton;
        DS: TDataSource;
        CDS: TClientDataSet;
        DBG: TDBGrid;
        SD: TSaveDialog;
        RG: TRadioGroup;
        E1: TEdit;
        E2: TEdit;
        L1: TLabel;
        L2: TLabel;
        B1: TSpeedButton;
        B4: TSpeedButton;
        B5: TSpeedButton;
        OD: TOpenDialog;
    var
        FN, FDragOfs: Integer;
        FDragging: Boolean;

    procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       FN := 1;
       RG.ItemIndex := 0;
    end;

    on Button Create --->

    try
       FN := FN + 1;
       CDS.Active := false;
    with CDS.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
    begin
       Name := E1.Text;
    case RG.ItemIndex of
       0 :
    begin
       DataType := ftString;
       Size := StrToInt(E2.Text);
    end;
       1 :
       DataType := ftInteger;
    end;

    end;
       CDS.CreateDataSet;
       E1.Text := 'Field'+IntToStr(FN);
       RG.ItemIndex :=0;
    finally
       CDS.Active := True;
    end;

    on Button Export To File ---->

    if not SD.Execute then
       exit
    else
    begin
       CDS.SaveToFile(SD.filename,dfxml);
       CDS.Active := false;
       CDS.FileName := SD.FileName;

    on Button Delete --->

        CDS.Fields.Remove (DBG.Columns.Items [DBG.SelectedIndex] .Field);
        //DBG.Columns.Delete(DBG.SelectedIndex);
        DBG.Columns.RebuildColumns;

    DB Structur e.g like this : 

        <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
         <DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
        <METADATA>
        <FIELDS>
        <FIELD attrname="Number" fieldtype="i4"/>
        <FIELD attrname="Date" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20"/>
        <FIELD attrname="Name" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20"/>
        <FIELD attrname="Phone" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20"/>
        <FIELD attrname="Address" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20"/>
        <FIELD attrname="Manager" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20"/>
        </FIELDS>
        <PARAMS/>
        </METADATA>
        <ROWDATA>
        </ROWDATA>
        </DATAPACKET>
```

so the question of how way I can remove / replace(rename or modified) with another name field that I do not want when Run-Time, i want to delete this line.
 example:

```
<FIELD attrname = "Date" fieldtype = "string" WIDTH = "20" />
```

after I remove Field does not appear, but when I took my application and re-run the database load sa'at back again as before.

sorry about my English.

Comment: You need to save the CDS without the field you deleted. Since you haven't shown how you're loading it, it's hard to say how to do so. If you're using an XML or binary CDS (standalone), you can use `SaveToFile`. If the data is coming from an external source (an actual DB somewhere, for instance) via a `DataSetProvider`, you need to modify your SQL statement (and remove the persistent field in the IDE), or delete it at startup using code (see the `CDS.FieldDefs` property).

Comment: on button save to file like this, if not SD.Execute then
   exit
else
begin
   CDS.SaveToFile(SD.filename,dfxml);
   CDS.Active := false;
   CDS.FileName := SD.FileName;
end;

Comment: I don't know what `SD` is, so I don't know what `SD.Execute` does. (`SD` = `TSaveDialog`, maybe?) I can't see your code from where I sit. Please don't add details in comments; [edit] your question and add them there instead, where they can be properly formatted and where people can see them. Again, do you have persistent fields (added at design-time with the Field Editor)? If so, you need to remove it using the `CDS.FieldDefs`, as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Once again, *please do not add content in comments*. Please [edit] your question instead, and add the information there. We're also not going elsewhere to see the DB structure; you can include it as a text table in your question when you edit. The information needed must be *here*, in the question itself, so future readers have access to it. Thanks.